# How does System.out.println() works on binary data?

Tags: java, binary, system.out, octal, number-systems

I am unable to understand the output of the below code

package beg;

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
public class Hell
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.out.println(10+010); //Prints 18
        System.out.println(010+010); //Prints 16
        System.out.println(010+10); //Prints 18
    }
}
```

Can somebody please explain?

Comment: When you add a `0` infront of a integer literal, its considered a `Octal` number. Hence `010` is `8` in decimal.

Comment: A number starting with 0 is written  using octal notation. So 010 = 1x8 + 0 = 8.

Answer (score 4):

When you write **`010`** its **octal code**... **not binary**

```
System.out.println(10+010); 
System.out.println(010+010); 
System.out.println(010+10);
```

These above lines are equivalent to:

```
System.out.println(10+8); // 010 being code for 8
System.out.println(8+8); 
System.out.println(8+10)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not binary its summation of octal numbers. In java number started by 0 are octal. And output is in decimal.

010 = 8 .

```
System.out.println(10+010);
```

10 + 8

```
System.out.println(010+010);
```

8 + 8

```
System.out.println(010+10);
```

8 + 10